# Boundary under linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given a linear transformation matrix $G\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ (m<n) with full row rank (i.e., rank($G$) = m) and a convex set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ whose boundary set is denoted by $\partial A$, the image of $A$ under $G$ is $B$ (i.e., $B = G(A), B\subset \mathbb{R}^m$) whose boundary set is denoted as $\partial B$. Do we have $G(\partial A) \rightarrow \partial B$? Could you please suggest some references about this question? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: No. Think about an orthogonal projection $G:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2$, then e.g. the boundary of a ball $A$ is a full disk (the closure of $G(A)$) and not a circle.

Comment: @Berci Many thanks for your answer! This is a very straight forward example. I have a follow-up question wondering if you could answer. If n < m and $G\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ has full column rank, do we have $G(\partial A)\rightarrow \partial B$?

Comment: These correspond to*embeddings*. It depends how you define boundary. What is the boundary of a flat disk in 3d?